# Flex container not displaying horizontal images, but vertical, how do I correct this in React?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I'm just looping through array and displaying each element inside a component. The images are being displayed vertically, but the flex container direction is column. How do I solve this issue?
I even tried inline styling but didn't work. Any ideas?

I've pasted the images being displayed vertically, but can't make it horizontally.

cheers

```
<div className="wrapper">
  <div className="flex-container">
    {<div>{products && products.map(((prod, index) => {
      return (
      <>
        <img style={{ width: "200px", height: "200px" }} src={`images/${prod.img}`} alt="" />
        <h4>{prod.productName}</h4>
        <p>{prod.price}</p>
      </>
      );
      }))}
    </div>}

  </div>
</div>
```

---

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.flex-container
{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: no-wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-basis: 25%;
}
```

[The resulting images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwLB7.png)

Comment: Can you make a sandbox, so that It can be easy to understand what exactly is the problem here...

Comment: The direction should be "row".

Comment: when I use float: right, without using flex container, I can get the result displayed horizontally, not just sure why the flex container is not working, oh well. thanks guys.